# Convert PDF to Excel

Tags: java, python, pdf

How to convert the table which is inside the pdf to excel .

I have tried some online tools but it was giving 60% result.

The sample table which contains in my pdf is given below.
[image]
I have hidden the field which contains name filed.

Comment: Converting PDF(s) (*which are usually rendered as images*) to Excel is notoriously difficult at best.

Comment: Is there anyother way to do it

Comment: Go get the original data source that produced this PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting data out from a pdf file is pretty messy. If the pdf table is ordered and has got a unique pattern embedded along with it, the best way to get the data is by converting the pdf to xml. For this you can use: **pdftohtml**.

Installation: `sudo apt-get install pdftohtml`

Usage: `pdftohtml -xml *Your File.pdf* *Output File.xml*`

You can run this command directly in the terminal.

The xml file which you will get now will have tags just like html which you can use to get the data from the generated xml output.

PS: One thing to be noted if the pdf table is not ordered then it becomes very difficult to get the data out from that xml because the tags will have some attributes which will not match the pattern. In that case you will need to hard code things.

Comment: I do wonder how well this will work given that the OP tried a few online solutions that didn't quite meet his/her expectations :)

Comment: exactly I was myself involved in parsing pdf data but getting data out of a pdf is a pain in the arse...especially when the data is not structured. Anyways he/she can try it if that works for him/her. :) Online softwares themselves do not generate the desired output and I remember there was one online website which used to generate that but again it had manual labour apart from coding.