# PDFminer Skips lines or misplaces string lines

Tags: python, file, file-io, io, pdfminer

I've developed a program that reads PDF files, but I noticed that the tool I'm using to read them (PDFminer) seems to  misplace text or not place it at all. 
The output seems to be very clear and accurate. It respects spacing and line jumps so the outputs looks more likely the original PDF. However, it seem to skip some lines (happens once in a file I checked) and misplace lines (happened twice in a document where the misplaced lines have the pattern of 10 others, so why only in these two?)

The code that retrieves lines is this one:

```
def extract(fname,docPage):
    pages=[docPage,docPage]
    pagenums = set(pages)

    output = StringIO()
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)

    infile = file(fname, 'rb')
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    infile.close()
converter.close()
text = output.getvalue().decode("utf8")
output.close

return text
```

any ideas? or have anyone faced this issue?  I've researched about this issue but with no results. Maybe an approach with any other tool (like pyPdf2)

Comment: A portable document format (pdf) does not have data in a structured way. Any piece of code to extract the data from a pdf fails if the code follows a particular format to get the data out from a pdf. Use any library the result will end in a mishap. So you need to hard code some things. Use a debugger in that case. You can check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30370507/convert-pdf-to-excel/30371480?noredirect=1#comment48834304_30371480 which converts the data into xml, from there you can understand why some of your lines are missing.